# How to control Add New options of Asset Publisher in Liferay 6.1?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I need Asset Publisher portlet present in my site. The admin will put the portlet into the page. The user who is belongs to a custom role should be able to add only "Basic Document". I don't want to show all other options in Add New. 
What should I do for achieving this? I could not find any way to do it by defining permissions of my custom role.

[image: Image of Add New]
Here I shown four options in the image. In that I want to allow my user to add only "Basic Document". How to remove other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Configure the Asset Type in the Configuration to "Documents and Media" so that only that type could be added in this specific Asset Publisher.